# Insert element at specific position, single concatenated list

Tags: c, list, function

my task is to write a function in C. This function should work as follows:

```
int insert_pos(int v, int pos, list * l)
```

The function is to insert a new list element with the value `v` at the position pos into the list `l`. The position of the head element of a list is always 0.
If pos is not a position in list `l`, the function should return -1, otherwise 0.
This is a single concatenated list.

Unfortunately I have no real approach how to do this.

I am happy about your help!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  What is `list`?

Comment: There is no list initialized, only defined.

Comment: I mean, what type is `list`?

Comment: List of integers

Comment: So, `typedef int list;`?

Comment: Yes, Exactly :)

Comment: Oops!  Shouldn't have deleted my comment: "Are you familiar with `memmove` from string.h?"

Comment: no problem :) 

no, we haven't used that yet

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple insertion using `memmove` from string.h.  `memmove`, as the name suggests, moves a block of memory from one location to another, even if the two regions overlap.  So,

```
memmove(l+pos+1,l+pos,(lengh_of_list-pos)*sizeof(int));
```

You can now insert the value:

```
l[pos] = value;
```

Warning: You will need to worry about whether or not the list is large enough to contain an additional value.